# How to lock desktop screen in Qt?

Tags: qt

Is there a function in desktop Qt that performs screen locking(an alternative to pressing <kbd>Windows</kbd> + <kbd>L</kbd> in Windows OS). I need this to work on all platforms Win, Mac, Lin.

For Windows I found platform function `LockWorkStation()` that does the job.

I want to make a small app for kids which will lock PC after some time to make them rest from PC.

Comment: I think you would have to call the platforms native API

Comment: [There](http://stackoverflow.com/questions/7120055/qt-screen-locker)  you have answer for Linux.